# Unable to start X Server with no screens, no xorg.config to edit

Tags: debian, x11, xorg, monitors, x-server

I am trying to start the X server (I have all the packages installed).

The problem I am having is that the server is offsite, has no screen and never has had a screen connected to it and as a result X Server has never run which means there is no xorg.config which from other posts I see can be used to start X server with out any screens.

I have tried running `X -configuration` (can't remember the command but I used the right one) and it output the same message that I get when I do `startx` which is `Fatal Error: no screens`

I need to find a way to start X server without connecting a screen to it.

Comment: check out the "xrdp" software. It allows for multiple headless X sessions to start, and you can connect to them remotely through several clients even rdesktop.

Comment: Are we correct in thinking that you want headless X11: so you can run a program that insists on displaying stuff, but you don't want to look at?

Comment: xrdp is not headless: it is a protocol converter. The head will be somewhere else. But it will be somewhere.

Comment: @richard I am making an program that renders using OpenGL and I need to get an OpenGL context. The way I am trying to do this is by using `glx` which seems to require that you have X server running in order to get the GL context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for headless with X. It's little bit described on [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Headless_With_X), there's shown a way how to do this.

There's another alternative to run headless X11 compatible server: [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)(X virtual framebuffer). It's a display server that performs all graphical operations in memory without showing any screen output.

**startx** is just front-end for [**xinit**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc) which setups X.Org server and clients(Window Manager, Desktop Environment,...). Among other things, it reads client side configuration from `~/.xinitrc`.

To run common user session inside virtual framebuffer:

1. start `Xfvb` and setup environment - `export` proper environment variables
2. execute `~/.xinitrc` script that defines X client setup of user

You may alternatively execute custom commands, that would setup WM, DM, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed the frame buffer for what I am doing as well. I will try those out and report back.

Comment: I followed the directions of the ArchWiki link and I am still getting the same error, http://pastebin.com/AfF024iQ

I am not able to reboot the server, I can only attempt to start X server with `sudo startx`

Comment: I also attempted to start a display with Xvfb and then `sudo startx` but that did not have any impact.

Comment: Ehm... `Xvfb` starts it's own X server. `startx` is front-end for `xinit` and it starts classic X server. So you don't `startx` after starting `Xvfb`. Why do you want to execute `startx` command?

Comment: I was told `startx` starts the x server, but if I can use Xvfb for an X server I guess I don't need to.
When using OpenGL in C++ do I still link to X11 or are their different libraries to link to for Xvfb?

Comment: If you develop in OpenGL you link (indirectly via GLFW, SDL,... ) to GLX. It's client side library of X11 protocol. It also create OpenGL context. X11 defines interaction between applications(clients), Window Manager(client) and backend X11 server.

You also link to OpenGL libraries and gl*** functions interact with current OpenGL context, which is set up by GLX library.

Comment: I was able to run my program in similar manner as what is shown in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281998/can-i-run-glu-opengl-on-a-headless-server

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you want some variant of vnc. It runs an X server on Linux machines and the result can be displayed remotely. If you don't want to see the screen anywhere use the older answers about headless X servers.

Comment: I am working on a project that uses rendering for analytics, so it outputs a sort of texture in the form of a png or jpg once it finishes, so there isn't a need to view it.
Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into it since it may help during development to be able to see the output live.